# undefined function mysql_connect() from terminal

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I have recently installed [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) in my machine(ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit) and thereafter mysql_connect() is not working from terminal(via CRON JOB as well). But then working fine through browser.

I followed [these](http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php#114837) steps to install pthreads

```
# Required libraries
sudo apt-get install gcc make libzzip-dev libreadline-dev libxml2-dev \
libssl-dev libmcrypt-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev lib32bz2-dev 

# Download PHP
cd /usr/local/src

wget http://www.php.net/distributions/php-<version>.tar.gz
( e.g. wget http://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.5.8.tar.gz )

# Extract
tar zxvf php-<version>.tar.gz
(e.g. tar zxvf php-5.5.8.tar.gz )

# Configure
cd /usr/local/src/php-<version>
( e.g. cd /usr/local/src/php-5.5.8 )

./configure --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --enable-maintainer-zts

# Compile
make && make install
( make -j3 && make -j3 install) -> Faster building

# Copy configuration
cp php.ini-development /etc/php.ini

# Install pthreads
pecl install pthreads
echo "extension=pthreads.so" >> /etc/php.ini

# Check installation
php -m | grep pthreads
```

**Note**: Previously I was using PHP 5.3.10. Now with this installation upgraded to PHP 5.5.8.
Also I tried adding

`extension=mysql.so`

into the php.ini file in following locations as well.

> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
>
> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your question would be more relevant, and receive more help, over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). Stack Overflow mostly deals with programming question and less so about server setups.

Comment: Note: You could use `php --ini` to find the loaded config file from the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should read more like:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr \
            --with-config-file-path=/etc \
            --enable-maintainer-zts \
            --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
            --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
            --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
```

See:

```
./configure --help
```

For options.

*Note that mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or pdo-mysql instead*

Comment: Mysql error is fixed and started getting new one "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init()"

while checking phpinfo(), cURL support is enabled. Still not getting. Any idea?

Comment: ```--with-curl``` should do it, remember to make clean between builds ;)